# Algorithm to find average of group of numbers

Tags: algorithm

I have a quite small list of numbers (a few hundred max) like for example this one:

> 117 99 91 93 95 95 91 97 89 99 89 99
>   91 95 89 99 89 99 89 95 95 95 89 948
>   189 99 89 189 189 95 186 95 93 189 95
>   189 89 193 189 93 91 193 89 193 185 95
>   89 194 185 99 89 189 95 189 189 95 89
>   189 189 95 189 95 89 193 101 180 189
>   95 89 195 185 95 89 193 89 193 185 99
>   185 95 189 95 89 193 91 190 94 190 185
>   99 89 189 95 189 189 95 185 95 185 99
>   89 189 95 189 186 99 89 189 191 95 185
>   99 89 189 189 96 89 193 189 95 185 95
>   89 193 95 189 185 95 93 189 189 95 186
>   97 185 95 189 95 185 99 185 95 185 99
>   185 95 190 95 185 95 95 189 185 95 189
>   2451

If you create a graph with X=the number and Y=number of times we see the number, we'll have something like this:
[image: Distribution]

What I want is to know the average number of each group of numbers. In the example, there's 4 groups and the resulting numbers are *92, 187, 948 and 2451*

The number of groups of number is not known.

Do you have any idea of how to create a (simple if possible) algorithm do extract these resulting numbers (if possible in c or pseudo code or English :)

Comment: What does this have to do with php?

Comment: average overall numbers?

Comment: Define a "group" ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-clustering might help

Comment: @jonsca: because my program is in php but indeed, it not a good idea to add the tag, i m removing it.

Comment: Brian Roach: I think it's the main issue, i don't know how to define a group. On the graph it's "obvious" for a human that there are 4 distinct numbers but i don't know how to define that mathematically.

Comment: @acemtp : How do you come up with those four numbers? What makes them "distinct"? The list of numbers you gave has 21 different distinct values, not 4 -- 89, 91, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 99, 101, 117, 180, 185, 186, 189, 190, 191, 193, 194, 195, 948, 2451

Comment: @marcog: clustering is exactly what I want to do indeed. I'll check the wiki page to see if they have simple algo to do that

Comment: @ildjarn: 89 91 93 95 96 97 99 101 117 are in the same "group" representing by mean value 92. They are in fact the same number with an error or +-20

Comment: @acemtp : Ah, understood, I finally see what you're getting at.

Comment: If these numbers are coming out of a database it might be faster to have the database do the calculation for you (depending on the database)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to do is called clustering.  If the data you've shown is typical, a gready approach, such as [neighbor joining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbor-joining), should be sufficient.  So the procedure is:

```
1) Apply neighbor joining
2) Apply an (empirically identified) threshold to define the clusters
3) Calculate average of each cluster
```

Using a package that already has clustering algorithms, such as R, would probably be the easiest course, though neighbor joining is not a particularly hard algorithm.

Comment: Indeed, you are right, i want to do clustering. I'll check your link.

Comment: On second thought, [single linkage clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-linkage_clustering) might be more appropriate here.  Its sensitive to noise, but if your data are that well separated, its simpler to implement.

Comment: Yes, the data are well separated.

Answer (score 0):

I think `std::map<int,int>` can easily solve this problem. The *key* of the map would be the number, and *value* would be the times/frequency the number occurs.

So the average can be calculated as,

```
int average = (m[key] * key) / count;
```

Where `count` is total number of numbers, so it calculates the average of each group over all numbers, as you didn't clearly mention what you mean by average. I'm also assuming that each distinct number forms its own group!

Comment: He needs an algorithm to find to the spikes in the graph. The numbers are clustered around each spike.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way:

1. Decide what width your bins will be. Let's say 10 (i.e. e.g. numbers > -5 and <= 5 go into bin 0, numbers > 5 and <= 15 go into bin 1, ...).
2. Create a list which holds lists to the number in each bin. I'd go with something like `map<unsigned int, vector<unsigned int> * >` in C++.
3. Now iterate over the numbers, decide what bin they belong to. Check if there's already a vector for this bin in your map, if not create one. Add the number to the vector.
4. After iterating over all the numbers, simply calculate the average of each vector.

Comment: The problem is that i have no idea of the bins width. It can be 10 on this example, but it can be 100 or 1000 or other list of number.

Comment: Well, you could first take your list of numbers, discard the top and bottom 5% (so you don't have outliers), calculate max - min and divide this by a certain contanst (e.g. 20, for 20 bins over the range max - min). That will give you a starting bin width to work with.

Answer (score 0):

So you are looking for "spikes" in the graph. I'm guessing you are interested in the size and position of each group?

You might use something like this:

```
Sort the numbers
Loop:
  Take the highest number you have 
  Investigate more numbers until you find a number that is too small to belong to the group (maybe 5% smaller)
  Calculate the average of the selected numbers 
  Let the discarded number be the last number
End loop
```

Comment: 948 and 2451 appear only one time but are important because they are representing a group by themselves.

Comment: Using my algorithm you will first encounter 2451. Next number is 948 which is much smaller than 2451, so the first group will be 2451. Next group will start with 948 an then the next number is 195 which is again much smaller, so 948 is group 2. Group three will be comprised of 195 and down to 185, cut off by 117. Next group is 117 and last group is 99 to 89.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you could do it like this:

```
$array = array(//an array of numbers);

$average = array_sum($array) / count($array);
```

With multiple groups of numbers you can do something like:

```
$array = array(
               array(array of numbers, group1),
               array(array of numbers, group2),
               //etc.
              );

foreach($array as $numbers)
{
     $average[] = array_sum($numbers) / count($numbers);
}
```

Unless you're looking for the median or mode.

Ah, I see what you're asking now, you're not asking how to find the average, you're asking how to group the numbers up and find the average of each group.

Lets see, you'd have to find the mode, `$counts = array_count_values($array)); array_keys(max($counts));` will do that and the keys in `$counts` will be the values of the original array, with the values in `$counts` being the number of times that each number shows up.  Then you need to figure out where the bigger gaps in the keys in `$counts` are.  You could also `array_unique()` the array original array and find the gaps in the values.

Wish my statistics teacher had done a bit more than play poker with us, or I could probably figure out the exact statistical method to determine how big the range checked to determine the groups should be.

Comment: The group are not known, they are in the list of the number and have to be found by the algo.